# MySQL master-master replication between database running on 3 different server

Tags: database, mysql, database-replication

I am trying to implement a master-master replication between 3 MySQL Databases running on 3 different servers.

I implemented master-master replication for 2 servers, but can't figure out how can I implement if for 3 different MySQL Servers (even plan to extend beyond 3, but later).

Any suggestions / pointers in this direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you doing the automatic fail over in case of primary master is down with your existing master-master setup. I am supposed to do the automatic fail over with cake php and i am stuck up. -Uday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is look at circular replication.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html